# Is there an event after Barcode Scan is Finished?

Tags: java, swing, events, listener, keylistener

I have a simple USB barcode reader which I intend to use to scan  barcodes. I know that just scanning the barcode while having a jtextfield on focus will get me the text input of the barcode I'm scanning. However my requirement is a bit different.

I need to create a java application where upon reading a barcode it will check the read barcode with a list I have to see whether it exists. The problem is I cannot keep a text box on my app in focus all the time as the app does other things as well. Instead what I want is for my program to keep looking for some sort of "event" which will be raised once the bar code scanners scans a code.

So does anyone know if there is such an event which will be raised when the barcode is scanned some code so I can instruct my program to do the rest of the work when the scanners scans a barcode?

Comment: *"..the rest of the work.."* What work, specifically, does your code do? How do you connect to the bar scanner? Makes me think it might be like we would do a `ServerSocket` - a `Thread` checks for new connections - it must then have functionality to update the GUI when it gets a new connection (or new message from an existing client).

Comment: TextField1.addCaretListener(new CaretListener() {

           
            public void caretUpdate(CaretEvent e) {
                   System.out.println("hellow");
            }
        }); me I want the word hello is not going to repeat 5 times when my bar code containing 5 characters